# HowTo: Visio SDK page Re-Layout FlowChart Top to Bottom

Tags: layout, sdk, visio, flowchart, autolayout

I'm creating a dynamic VSD from a hierarchical set of data that represents a flowchart. I don't want/need to fuddle with absolute positioning of these elements - the automatic layout options will work just fine.

The problem is I can't figure out how to perform this command via code. In the UI (Visio 2010), the commands are on the ribbon here: Design (tab) -> Layout (group) -> Re-Layout (SplitButton).

Any of these will do. Looking through the Visio SDK documentation and Googling for a couple days have turned up nothing of very much use.

Any ideas? (using C#, but VB/VBA would do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Page.Layout() method itself is not enough.

In the WBSTreeView.sln sample project (VB.Net) I found how to accomplish this, but couldn't post my answer until 8 hours later :-x

The other layout types are possible by looking through the enums used below.
Compact -> DownRight just ended up being better for most of the flows we're creating.

Translated to C#:

```
        // auto-layout, Compact Tree -> Down then Right
        var layoutCell = this._page.PageSheet.get_CellsSRC(
            (short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
            (short)VisRowIndices.visRowPageLayout,
            (short)VisCellIndices.visPLOPlaceStyle);
        layoutCell.set_Result(
            VisUnitCodes.visPageUnits,
            (short)VisCellVals.visPLOPlaceCompactDownRight);
        layoutCell = this._page.PageSheet.get_CellsSRC(
            (short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
            (short)VisRowIndices.visRowPageLayout,
            (short)VisCellIndices.visPLORouteStyle);
        layoutCell.set_Result(
            VisUnitCodes.visPageUnits,
            (short)VisCellVals.visLORouteFlowchartNS);

        //// to change page orientation
        //layoutCell = this._page.PageSheet.get_CellsSRC(
        //    (short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
        //    (short)VisRowIndices.visRowPrintProperties,
        //    (short)VisCellIndices.visPrintPropertiesPageOrientation);
        //layoutCell.set_Result(
        //    VisUnitCodes.visPageUnits,
        //    (short)VisCellVals.visPPOLandscape);

        // curved connector lines
        layoutCell = this._page.PageSheet.get_CellsSRC(
            (short)VisSectionIndices.visSectionObject,
            (short)VisRowIndices.visRowPageLayout,
            (short)VisCellIndices.visPLOLineRouteExt); 
        layoutCell.set_Result(
            VisUnitCodes.visPageUnits, 
            (short)VisCellVals.visLORouteExtNURBS);


        // perform the layout
        this._page.Layout();
        // optionally resize the page to fit the space taken by its shapes
        this._page.ResizeToFitContents();
        //
```

**Changing Connector Line Colors**

If you're unfamiliar with how formulas for colors work, this might also be very frustrating. [By default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa223354%28v=office.11%29.aspx) you can give an int as a string to get pre-defined colors, but this isn't very helpful because there isn't an easy way to figure out what each of those colors are. (There is a Page.Colors collection, but you have to inspect each of their RGB values and figure out the color from them.)

Instead, you can use your own RGB values for the formula.

```
    private void SetConnectorLineColor(Shape connector, string colorFormula)
    {
        var cell = connector.get_Cells("LineColor");
        cell.Formula = colorFormula;
    }

    internal static class AnswerColorFormula
    {
        public static string Green = "RGB(0,200,0)";
        public static string Orange = "RGB(255,100,0)";
        public static string Yellow = "RGB(255,200,0)";
        public static string Red = "RGB(255,5,5)";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the [Layout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff765900) method on the [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767035) object. If there are shapes selected on this page then this method will only operate on the current selection. You may want to call [DeselectAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff767441) on the [ActiveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff766851) first.